# How to add delimiter to my code

Tags: vba, excel

I really need help with the following code. I want to add delimiter after the value of the cell. I am quite new to vba, so please let me know if you need more detailed information :

```
Sub NameSplit()

    Dim var As Variant
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
           If CBool(Len(.Cells(rw, "F").Value2)) Then
                var = Split(.Cells(rw, "F").Value2, Chr(32))
                .Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, UBound(var) + 1) = var

            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for my poor coding :(

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which cell? Your are trying to convert a value to a Boolean using the length of the value? Then split it at the space? Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: I have data in column "F" and want to split it in 4 columns (A:D); the data in column "F" is taken from other sheets in the workbook by formulas. it transfers the info that contains of no characters into columns "A:D", but the ones, separated by ";" are transferred only in column "A"

Comment: First what are you trying to achieve with this statement? `If CBool(Len(.Cells(rw, "F").Value2))` Second, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: honestly, I don't know... it's a code I found on the web, that I just adjusted to be working to some point... it separates the following in column F ( Needs Manual Check) into 3 separates columns ( A-needs; B-manual; C-check), but it does not separate the following - VDG6BXI;SP876GF;SPKLAH09;SPKZHG8GF

Comment: So re you trying to split `VDG6BXI;SP876GF;SPKLAH09;SPKZHG8GF` into 4 columns (A-D) at the semicolon `;`?

Comment: Yes, that is what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try `TextToColumns`:

```
Sub NameSplit()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
                                                    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                    Semicolon:=True, _
                                                    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1))

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

```
Sub NameSplit()

    Dim var As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            var = Split(.Cells(rw, "F").Text, ";")
            .Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, UBound(var) + 1) = var
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that way it just copies the formula from column F and paste it into Column A only....there is a vlookup formula in F

Comment: Indeed, forgot it's a calculated field. Try the edit.

Comment: run-time error 13- type mismatch, highlighting var = Split(.Cells(rw, "F").Value2, ";")

Comment: thanks, it is working for those S3PARSOL13;S3PP7K13;S3PARMSSQ;S3PARHSSQ;SPBASSQ
... but now... "Needs Manual Check" appears only in one cell in column A....